# Not being able to store the cookie sent by the server in the browser. Using Axios in the front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, session-cookies

This is my express code where I am using express-session to create a storage and work with cookies. Since version 1.5.0 the module no longer needs cookie-parser to store the cookie in the req/res.

The session gets stored in a PSQL database hosted on ElephantSQL.

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvtY0.png)

The following code is the cors configuration of my express application and how I am handling req.body:

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX0p1.png)

The application is hosted on Railways.app: https://tradenow-authentication-production.up.railway.app/api

The following code is how I am making POST requests to the api in my front-end application where I am using React and Axios:

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yku3J.png)

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwcxX.png)

The issues are:

- I can't get any cookie stored in the browser when I run the app and try to log in. It stores 2 sessions in the database though, which really is a strange behaviour. However, when I run the Node app locally and I make a request to the localhost from my front-end, it all seems to work fine, only one session is created and the cookie is being stored.
- According to the logic, when I post a username or password that does not exist, it should return me a 404 error, but it returns a 401 error which should not work like that. Again, running the server locally, works fine.
- When using Insomnia to make these post requests to the deployed server using the URL, the behaviour is correct and the cookies are getting stored correctly and just 1 session is being created.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and the problem was on the axios call for some reason.. did you try to use the built in fetch instead of axios?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).